# Remove individual features from OSM in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio, threebox

I would like to use Mapbox GL JS (with 3D Buildings) for a new real estate project and place the 3D model of the building on the map (like https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model-threebox/).

However, there are still old houses at the location where the building is to be placed. These specific (2-3 buildings) should be removed before placement, otherwise there will be unsightly overlaps with the new building.

Is there a way I can do this in Mapbox/Mapbox Studio?

Comment: You could just filter them out on the client side using a set filter function if they have some sort of unique ID that they can be identified with. You might also be able to filter them out using a bounding box.